# Hovering text over field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to show a hovering text for the field term total in UI with the help of the tooltip. When the condition is true it should show hovering text when cursor is on Term Total and should get removed after condition becomes false but when true value is passing tooltip is getting added and after trying for false condition it is not getting removed it is still visible in UI even thought ClineBus is false

```
function TermTotal(cLineBus) {
        

        // Get the "term total" element
        const termTotal = document.querySelector("span#First_Term_Total_Label");

        if (cLineBus) {
          // Create a new div element for the tooltip
          const tooltip = document.createElement("div");
          tooltip.innerHTML = "<strong>Test Hover Msg</strong>"; // Display Text
          tooltip.style.display = "none";
          tooltip.style.position = "absolute";
          tooltip.style.color = "black"; //text color
          tooltip.style.backgroundColor = "white"; //Backfround color
          tooltip.style.border = "1px solid black"; // border stroke
          //tooltip.style.borderRadius = "5px"; // for curvered border
          tooltip.style.padding = "5px"; // toottip padding to adjust position
          tooltip.style.fontWeight = "bold"; // text style
          tooltip.style.fontSize = "18px"; // text fontsize

          function handleMouseOver() {
            // Append the tooltip to the document body
            document.body.appendChild(tooltip); 

            // Set the position of the tooltip
            const termTotalRect = termTotal.getBoundingClientRect();
            tooltip.style.top = termTotalRect.top + "px";
            tooltip.style.left = termTotalRect.left - tooltip.offsetWidth - 5 + "px";
            
            
            tooltip.style.display = "block";
          }; 

          termTotal.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            if(document.body.contains(tooltip)){
                document.body.removeChild(tooltip);
            }
          });

          termTotal.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
        } else {
          termTotal.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
          alert("Inside IF");
        }

      };
```

I tried passing values First as True and second as false every time the true value is getting passed tooltip is getting added  but not getting removed when condition is false

Comment: Can you, please, show what console.log(cLineBus) shows

Comment: When im passing true then it will display true in console same goes for false I noticed adding extra log comments and removeEventListner is not removing mouseover event

Comment: Because you have `function handleMouseOver() {...}` nested into `TermTotal`, you are creating a new instance of that function in the scope of `TermTotal`, every time you call the latter. But removing an event listener, needs the reference to the _exact_ function that was used when the event was added.

Comment: Ok I will try writing the scope of handelMouseOver(){} outside the of termTotal making it independent function